# Using multiprocess.Pool to call a function that requires many input arguments in parallel

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I am having some trouble with correctly implementing the multiprocess pool with the function I have defined here:

```
def run_ilqr(x0, N, max_iter, regu_init, alpha_init, x_dim, u_dim, n_agents, x_ref, x_ref_T):
    # First forward rollout
    u_trj = np.random.randn(N-1, n_agents*n_inputs)*0.0001
    x_trj = rollout(x0, u_trj, x_dim, u_dim)
    total_cost = cost_sum(x_trj, u_trj, x_dim, x_ref, x_ref_T)
    regu = regu_init
    max_regu = 10000
    min_regu = 0.01
    
    alpha = alpha_init
    max_alpha = 1.0
    min_alpha = 0.0
    
    # Setup traces
    cost_trace = [total_cost]
    expected_cost_redu_trace = []
    redu_ratio_trace = [1]
    redu_trace = []
    regu_trace = [regu]
    
    alpha_trace = [alpha]
    # Run main loop
    for it in range(max_iter):
        # Backward and forward pass
        
        k_trj, K_trj, expected_cost_redu = backward_pass(x_trj, u_trj, regu, alpha, x_dim, u_dim, x_ref_T, x_ref)
        
        x_trj_new, u_trj_new = forward_pass(x_trj, u_trj, k_trj, K_trj, expected_cost_redu, total_cost, alpha, x_dim, u_dim)
        # Evaluate new trajectory
        total_cost = cost_sum(x_trj_new, u_trj_new, x_dim, x_ref, x_ref_T)
        
        cost_redu = cost_trace[-1] - total_cost
        redu_ratio = cost_redu / abs(expected_cost_redu)
        # Accept or reject iteration
        if redu_ratio >= 1e-4 and redu_ratio <= 10  :
            # Improvement! Accept new trajectories and lower regularization
            redu_ratio_trace.append(redu_ratio)
            cost_trace.append(total_cost)
            x_trj = x_trj_new
            u_trj = u_trj_new
            regu *= 0.7
            # alpha doesn't change if accepted
        else:
            # Reject new trajectories and increase regularization
            regu *= 2.0
            alpha = alpha* 0.5 # a scaling factor of 0.5 for alpha is a typical value
            cost_trace.append(cost_trace[-1])
            redu_ratio_trace.append(0)
        regu = min(max(regu, min_regu), max_regu)
        regu_trace.append(regu)
        redu_trace.append(cost_redu)
        
        alpha = min(max(alpha,min_alpha),max_alpha)
        alpha_trace.append(alpha)
        
        # Early termination if expected improvement is small
        if expected_cost_redu <= 1e-6:
            break
            
    return x_trj, u_trj, cost_trace, regu_trace, redu_ratio_trace, redu_trace, alpha_trace
```

The details of the function above does not matter much, but it requires 10 input arguments, and among them `x0,x_ref,_x_ref_T` are a 1-dimensional vectors ( such as shape (12,) ), `N,max_iter,regu_init,alpha_init,n_agents` are scalars, `x_dim,u_dim` are list-like such as [4,4,4] or [2,2,2]. `x_trj,u_trj` are the most important return variable here, and they are 2-dimensional arrays.

I tried to call this `run_ilqr` function with Pool, and here is what I have done:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1) as p:
  p.starmap(run_ilqr,[first_args,N,max_iter,regu_init,alpha_init,second_args,third_args,fourth_args,fifth_args,sixth_args])
```

where `first_args, second_args` etc, are lists each of length 150, and for example,  `first_args` refers to `x0` in the input argument since I want to call the function with 150 different `x0` vectors. However, the following error pops up

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 121, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 47, in starmapstar
    return list(itertools.starmap(args[0], args[1]))
TypeError: run_ilqr() takes 10 positional arguments but 150 were given
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-88-628be8ab875b> in <module>()
      1 with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1) as p:
----> 2   p.starmap(run_ilqr,[first_args,N,max_iter,regu_init,alpha_init,second_args,third_args,fourth_args,fifth_args,sixth_args])

1 frames
/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in starmap(self, func, iterable, chunksize)
    274         `func` and (a, b) becomes func(a, b).
    275         '''
--> 276         return self._map_async(func, iterable, starmapstar, chunksize).get()
    277 
    278     def starmap_async(self, func, iterable, chunksize=None, callback=None,

/usr/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py in get(self, timeout)
    655             return self._value
    656         else:
--> 657             raise self._value
    658 
    659     def _set(self, i, obj):

TypeError: run_ilqr() takes 10 positional arguments but 150 were given
```

I looked up some examples for `pool.starmap`, and it seems like I just needed to pass in a list of input arguments for each variable, which is what I have tried to do. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass a list of iterables to [starmap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap). If some of your arguments remain constant, while others change, you would still need to create a list (or some other iterable) of them. If each of `first_args, second_args`, etc. are of length 150, and you want to create 150 tasks, then try this:

```
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(multiprocessing.cpu_count()-1) as p:
  p.starmap(run_ilqr,[[first_args[i],N,max_iter,regu_init,alpha_init,second_args[i],third_args[i],fourth_args[i],fifth_args[i],sixth_args[i]] for i in range(150)])
```